# Is there a way to make a textbox in JS Excalibur or place one on top of the game?

Tags: javascript, textbox

I want to put a textbox that can be changed in height, width and position.  It needs to fit atleast 3 lines of words in a font size of 24.

I am using the framework Excalibur which is running my entire game. Excalibur has both label and text, but neither can wrap around itself to imitate a textbox as far as I can read in the documentation. If I try to put my strings in them, they will leave the screen in 1 singular line.

I tried to put a span in the index.html and then fill that with text through DOM manipulation, but I cannot get the span on top of the game. I gave it a Z-index of 999 and even that didn't solve it. It is just stuck above/to the left of my game screen and it wont move on top of it with transform-translate(x, y).

Is there another way I could go about this?